# product thumble image not showing in order by page but it will display in product detail page

Tags: virtuemart

product thumble image not showing in order by page but it will display in product detail page...
how can i solve these problem
site url is::

http://botguruz.com/buy-a-bot.html?page=shop.browse&category_id=1

Answer (score 0):

You're using

```
http://botguruz.com/components/com_virtuemart/shop_image/product/resized/AutoPilot_Tweet_4b25d47121120_90x90.jpg
```

for the working image and

```
http://botguruz.com/components/com_virtuemart/show_image_in_imgtag.php?filename=resized/AutoPilot_Tweet_4b25d47121120_90x90.jpg&newxsize=90&newysize=90&fileout=
```

for the broken image. Spot the difference.

Comment: i dont understand visit url given below 
http://botguruz.com/buy-a-bot.html?page=shop.browse&category_id=1